# can I connect nodejs with teradata (any nodejs npm for this)?

Tags: node.js, jdbc, npm, teradata

Is there anyway I can connect teradata to nodejs server? I have use case where I need to pull teradata information in my rest APIs.

Can I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) npm package?

Comment: maybe? have you tried jdbc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Absolutely. It will work just fine. Please find the configuration below.

```
var config = {
    libpath: './jar/terajdbc4.jar',
    libs: ['./jar/tdgssconfig.jar'],
    drivername: 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
    url: 'jdbc:teradata://myteradata.test.com',
    // optionally
    user: 'sr0898',
    password: '***',
};

jdbc.initialize(config, function(err, res)
```

The key is to have the jars downloaded and referred to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Node.js Teradata Driver Now Available**

The Teradata nodejs-driver node module is a Database API Specification v2.0 compliant driver for Node.js and the Teradata SQL Engine.

**Includes**

- Typescript / Javascript npm module
- Database API Specification v2.0 compliant driver
- 127 Unit Tests
- Examples Guide
- Documentation for Setup and Running, Connection Parameters, Stored Password Protection, Data Types, Module Exceptions

**Supported Platforms**

- Node.js:

  - 8.x, 9.x, 10.x, 11.x
- Operating Systems:

  - Apple macOS, Microsoft Windows, Linux

Github repo:
https://github.com/Teradata/nodejs-driver

NPM Module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/teradata-nodejs-driver

Comment: How do you specify the host and database correctly?  I keep getting: "Error: [Version 42659830765e8ee7b720b821cd0b35677b82dbd5] [Session 0] [Teradata SQL Driver] Failed to connect to myServer:1025"